# Does the ability to cast Cantrips qualify as "Ability to cast arcane spells" to take the Arcane Strike feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does the ability to cast Cantrips qualify as "Ability to cast arcane spells" to take the  Arcane Strike feat?

Building a Gestalt Rogue/Warlock (Adamant Entertainment ver). These guys get Cantrips = to their Charisma mod. However it not specified what type of cantrips  they can select from.

1) Does this mean I can choose any cantrips (0 level spells) from any source arcane or divine?

2) Does this qualify as "Ability to cast arcane spells" to take the  Arcane Strike feat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This GM would rule that the [warlock](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/adamant-entertainment/warlock/) special ability cantrips—that says only, "At 1st level, the warlock learns a number of cantrips equal to their CHA [*sic*] modifier"—*does*, in fact, meet the prerequisite *ability to cast arcane spells* of the feat [Arcane Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat). This GM finds it reasonable to assume the purpose of the warlock's class feature cantrips is to mimic the sorcerer's class feature [cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/#TOC-Cantrips) that's more verbose and actually explains what it does for the sorcerer:

> Sorcerers learn a number of cantrips, or 0-level spells, as noted on Table: Sorcerer Spells Known under “Spells Known.” These spells are cast like any other spell, but they do not consume any slots and may be used again.

Note that the warlock class dates from the 2009 book [*Tome of Secrets*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/63908?affiliate_id=189426), which is the very early days of *Pathfinder* material. The game's tech's come a long way since—be sure the GM is comfortable with your use of such material.

The term *cantrip* is always used in regard to arcane spells; the term *orisons* is used in regard to divine spells, like in the class features of the [cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/?scrlybrkr/../3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/adept-godling/archetypes/rogue-genius-games-adept-godling-archetypes/youxia/../3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/adept-godling/archetypes/rogue-genius-games-adept-godling-archetypes/weapon-champion/../3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/adept-godling/archetypes/rogue-genius-games-adept-godling-archetypes/youxia/../3rd-party-classes/super-g/#TOC-Orisons) and the [oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/#TOC-Orisons).

Comment: Interesting that even though they gain cantrips, it is not given any information about spellcasting those cantrips, we have only to guess that their DC is based off CHA, and cast at-will.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yeah, I know. I think the omissions really are due to the class's age, but I also don't own the bitware so I can't confirm if the official version's identical. As presented, though, it is pretty frickin' weird.